# Can't access Plex from outside my network

Tags: server, port-forwarding, mediaserver, plex

My firewall is configured to port forward traffic to `32400`.

When I log into `mydomain.com:32400/web` I am taken to my account and I can see my Plex server in the left pane. However I get the error: `We're Sorry, but we can not reach this server`.

Any help fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done all the proper port forwarding on your router?

[Look for a tutorial here.](http://portforward.com)

Comment: My router forwards me to the Plex server webpage when I'm accessing the network internally.

Comment: @Zach Exactly. You need to port forward so that you can access the internal things externally.

Comment: So yes, port forwarding has been done. Still can't see my data from externally.